# Adjust the distance only between two subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 subplots (3 rows and 1 column). We can use `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)` to adjust the distance between the subplots. this will change the distance between subplots for all case. How can I have different distance between plot 1 (311) & plot 2 (312), and plot 2 (312) & plot 3 (313)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good question. Try this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable 

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1) 
ax2 = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="100%", pad=0.5)
ax3 = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="100%", pad=1)
```

Then you would get:

[image]

Comment: Where does the function `make_axes_locatable` come from?

Comment: @DavidZwicker `from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable`