# Matplotlib - Set distance between two x axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I show an image (figure) with imshow which is like 5 times wider than its height. I add a second x-axis under this using this code:

```
newax = figure.add_axes(ax.get_position())
newax.patch.set_visible(False)
newax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
for spinename, spine in newax.spines.items():
   if spinename != 'bottom':
       spine.set_visible(False)
```

However, the second x axis is far below the first x axis.

Image
first xAxis
(huge space)
second xAxis

Setting the ylim to [0,0] doesn't work. How can I have the second x axis to be placed only a few pixels under the first x axis?

Edit: added minimal sample to help reproducing the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def addReferenceToPlot(figure, ax, xlim):
    newax = figure.add_axes(ax.get_position())
    newax.patch.set_visible(False)
    newax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    for spinename, spine in newax.spines.items():
        if spinename != 'bottom':
            spine.set_visible(False)
    newax.axvline(0.5, color='k', ls='dashed')

data = np.ones((25, 111))

specFig, specAx = plt.subplots()

addReferenceToPlot(specFig, specAx, data.shape[1])
specAx.imshow(data, origin="lower", interpolation="nearest")
specAx.set_xlim([0, data.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

Edit (added picture that looks like the intended result):
[image: The intended result]

Right now, the lower x-axis is far below the upper x-axis and the dashed line goes out of the plotted matrix. However, the two axes should be close to each other and the dashed line should stop at the "top" of the plotted matrix.

Comment: a) You should show your entire code if you want us to debug it, and b) if you're learning matplotlib you'd be better off starting with using `subplot` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you want ganged plots http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/ganged_plots.html? 

If you don't want them *that* tight, check out the tight-layout examples, http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/demo_tight_layout.html

Comment: plt.tight_layout() doesn't work. It only narrows the plot, but doesn't change the distance. However, I don't use plt.plot(), I use imshow() instead. And I already instantiate a subplot with 1 row and 1 column. I have the feeling, that the area where data is plotted is much larger than the area where the image is shown. It appears that the image is an rectangle within a huge square. How can I shrink this "plotting area" to the size of the image?

Comment: imshow() uses plot(). You're probably forcing a big subplot without realizing it. Give us a complete minimal example before claiming that the standards don't work.

Comment: You're right, I did so.

Comment: Now I can't tell what kind of result you want. I *suspect* that you are using finicky code when the right take on a standard subplot layout would work. Do you have a published figure with the layout you want, or can you sketch a dummy layout and post that?

Comment: I hope the constructed image helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
def plot_mix(image1, image2):
    ax.append(plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (1, 0)))
    ax[-1].imshow(image1)
    ax[-1].set_title('Mix Image 1')

    ax.append(plt.subplot2grid((3, 2), (2, 0)))
    ax[-1].imshow(image2)
    ax[-1].set_title('Mix Image 2')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Thanks to cphlewis and limes!

Comment: Another way: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662787/adjust-the-distance-only-between-two-subplots-in-matplotlib?rq=1)